# How do I restore new iphone settings?

Tags: iphone

I plugged my new iphone into my computer and it asked if I wanted to restore my old iphone settings.  I clicked yes not realizing I would lose everything from the last 8 months since I got the new phone.  Is there any way to restore what was on the new phone?

Answer (score 1):

Open iTunes preferences, there's a "Devices" tab that shows you any backups stored on that computer, but if you've never connected it in between I can hardly imagine there's an older backup.
Did you connect your phone to any computer in the last 8 months, or did you eventually use iCloud backups? You could check those as well..